# need some easy solutions with short code in string compression in js

Tags: javascript, string, data-structures, logic

Here I have created a program for string compression, so for input chars = ["a","a","b","b","c","c","c"] we are getting output like 6 characters ["a","2","b","2","c","3"]. So I have created a program using the array approach, which is very lengthy and complex too. Is there any solution using the two-pointer or recursion approach to solve that program with very little code and efficiency? Can you please provide that with very short code? The code is given below.

```
var compress = function(chars) {
 if (!chars.length) {
    return 0;
  }
   let j = 0;                 
  let cur = chars[0];        
  let counter = 0;         
   for (let i = 0; i <= chars.length; i++) {
  
    if (chars[i] === cur) {
      counter++;              
    } else {
      // Otherwise, add the current character and count to the compressed array
      chars[j] = cur;        
      if (counter > 1) {
        const s = counter.toString();
        for (let k = 0; k < s.length; k++) {
          chars[++j] = s[k];  
        }
      }
      j++;                  
      cur = chars[i];      
      counter = 1;           
    }
   }
   return j
};
console.log(compress ('aaaabbc'))//a4b2c
```

Comment: use two pointer approach.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding  foud this on google `const encode = (text) => text.replace(/([ \w])\1+/g, (group, chr) => chr + group.length );`

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) first.

Comment: Your code does not return a string, but an integer. The `console.log` will output 5, not "a4b2c". Did you run this code before posting?

Comment: Secondly, you describe the input  and output as an array, but then in your code you pass a string and claim in a code-comment that the output is a string too.  It is easy to convert one to the other, but it would help if your question was consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using two pointers. Key concept here is: **DO NOT PASS TWINCE FOR EACH ELEMENT IN THE INPUT**.

Complexity:

- time: **O(n)**
- space: **O(n)**

```js
const compress = (str) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ) {
    let j = i;
    while (str[j] == str[i]) {
      j++;
    }
    result.push(`${str[i]}${j - i == 1 ? '' : j - i}`);
    i = j;
  }
  return result.join('');
};
```

Comment: Due to your string manipulation this has a time complexity of O(²), not O().

Comment: @trincot Due to this **```result = `${result}${str[i]}${j - i == 1 ? '' : j - i}`;```** you said?

Comment: Yes, you create a new string each time. Let's say every character occurs in pairs in the input, then the first string `result` has size 2, the second version of `result` has size 4, the third has size 6. And each time this string is **created**, so the work done is 2 + 4 + 6 + ..., which is O(²)

Comment: @trincot You mean space complexity? Because I don't see the relation of your explanation and time.

Comment: When you assign concatenated strings to a string variable, every character needs to be copied into the newly allocated string memory. This represents work (time). Note that strings are immutable and you are not adding to a string, but creating a new one. Also space is affected, but that is countered by the fact that the previous value of `result` is discarded after the assignment has happened.

Comment: Yes, now it is O().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` on the input, and use a regular expression to match every occurrence of a repeated sequence (of size 2 or more). Then use the callback argument to replace this with the encoded version:

```js
const compress = chars => chars.replace(/(.)\1+/g, ({length},ch) => ch+length);

console.log(compress ('aaaabbc'))//a4b2c
```

Note that if your input has digits, then the output can be ambiguous. For instance, if the output is "a20" you could wonder whether the input was either "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "aa0".

Answer (score 1):

An one liner: you can use `Array::reduce()`:

```js
const result = ["a","a","b","b","c","c","c"]
  .reduce((r, c) => (r[r.length - 2] === c ? r[r.length - 1]++ : r.push(c, 1), r), []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the characters and take two variables for the actual character and count. The count starts with an empty string and get finally incremented for getting a count value, if the value is truthy. If not, only the character is added to the result string.

```js
const
    compress = chars => {
        if (!chars.length) return '';
        let result = '',
            char = '',
            count = '';

        for (const c of chars) {
            if (c === char) {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            result += char + (count && ++count);
            char = c;
            count = '';
        }
        return result + char + (count && ++count);
    };

console.log(compress('aaaabbc')); //a4b2c
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified two-pointer approach to avoid counter increments.
I have labeled the variables so you can follow the code easily.

```
var compress = function(chars) {
    let result = '';
    let currChar = 0;
    while(currChar < chars?.length) {
        let nextChar = currChar+1;
        while ((nextChar < chars.length) && (chars[currChar] === chars[nextChar]))
            nextChar++;
        let repeatFactor = nextChar-currChar;
        result += chars[currChar] + (repeatFactor > 1 ? (''+repeatFactor).trim() : '');
        currChar=nextChar;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope you will find this useful.